# How to define constructor with closure and factory method with Google Closure

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I'm trying to build a constructor function with the Google Closure library.

To do so, I have a closure that return a factory method that export the constructor:

```
(function(factory) {
    namespace.ui.Modal = factory();
})(function() {
    var Modal = function() {};
    goog.inherits(Modal, namespace.ui.Base);

    return Modal;
});
```

This fails the build with the closure compiler. How could I annotate this code so it works as is inside closure compiler?

Answer (score 0):

The standard pattern for a constructor would be:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
namespace.ui.Modal = function() {
  /** @private {string} */
  this.field = "oh no, not hello again";
}
goog.inherits(namespace.ui.Modal, namespace.ui.Base);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: And of course the field `field` is an exemplī grātia.